# Is this layout even possible with any type of CSS grid? (Flex, Grid, Box Model, etc.)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Struggling with `display: flex;`, and `display: grid;` on a parent element for a couple days here trying to make this layout work. This is the goal of what I'm trying to create:

[image]

Is this layout and flow possible for mobile and desktop?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sorfi939399/tez6qajy/)

### HTML

```
  <div class="item-table">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
    <div class="d">d</div>
    <div class="e">e</div>
    <div class="f">f</div>
  </div>
```

### SCSS

```
.item-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: flex-start;

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

  .a {
    flex: 1 8%;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  .b {
    flex: 1 30%;
    border: 1px solid red;

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      flex: 1 50%;
    }
  }

  .c {
    flex: 1 100%;
    border: 1px solid #f00;

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      order: 4;
      flex: 0 60%;
      margin-left: 0;
      align-self: left;
    }
}

  .d {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid red;

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      order: 6;
      flex: 0 20%;
    }
  }

  .e {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid red;

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      order: 5;
      flex: 0 20%;
    }
  }

  .f {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid red;

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      flex: 0 20%;
      order: 3;
    }
  }
}
```

Column A should be 8%. The percentages are mostly estimated and rounded. Not looking for absolute perfection on that, just trying to get proportions somewhat close to the example posted.

The problem I've been experiencing is that `C`, `D`, `E` are typically stacking down below `F` under 600px, since they are sharing a row when using `display: flex`.

Comment: since you are able to have a mockup/wireframe of it then it's possible

Comment: just because I can create it on illustrator doesn't mean it's possible with html/css right?

Comment: Am pretty sure you saw more complex layout than this ;) ... by the way if you were struggling for days show us what you have already done?

Comment: By the way, the answer is _yes_.

Comment: @cale_b see updates, thanks

Comment: @sol just col A which is 8%

Comment: @cale_b your comments are very constructive and did answer the question, not like many others! but I see this everywhere and that's not nice a lot of developers here are trying to learn and get help while people are being sarcastic. I won't call it rude but maybe not nice to say. anyway had to say it and sorry for that.

Comment: @sol no need to say names and I deleted the comment anyway. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using CSS Grid.

Start with the mobile layout, and on screens > `600px`, use a media query to trigger the more complex layout.

You can use `margin` to create the uneven heights.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tez6qajy/45/)

```css
.item-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: .5rem;
}

.item-table>div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.a,
.b {
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.f {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 4 / 6;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .item-table {
    grid-template-columns: 75px 30% 1fr 1.5fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  }
  .a {
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
  }
  .b {
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .a,
  .c,
  .d,
  .e {
    margin: .5rem 0
  }
  .f {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 2 / -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item-table">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
  <div class="e">e</div>
  <div class="f">f</div>
</div>
```